# D drive mounted and visible thro files, but not thro ap (Freecad), How do imake it appear?

Tags: drive

I can view and open files from Files, but thro freecad the D drive is not visible.
The drive is mounted.
ubuntu 22.04
drive is NTFS.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Is FreeCAD a snap?

Comment: ubuntu 22.04 
freecad 0.2 Snap
I've installed it via apt-get and can now see the d drive

Comment: Exactly. With the snap version all you'd had to do was enabling access to other locations. By default snaps are confined to your user's area.